# contacts not showing in activity

Tags: java, android, listview

I am trying to show contacts in an activity but its not working.
I review my code, But not able to understand whats the problem is.
Here is my code:-

/*deleted*/

showfriendlist.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lst_contacts"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
// The contacts from the contacts content provider is stored in this cursor
    mMatrixCursor = new MatrixCursor(new String[]{"_id", "name", "photo", "details"});

// Adapter to set data in the listview
    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),
            R.layout.lv_layout,
            mMatrixCursor,
            new String[]{"name", "photo", "details"},
            new int[]{R.id.tv_name, R.id.iv_photo, R.id.tv_details}, 0);
```

You are not passing the Cursor to `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

**Use Cursor to get Mobile contacts**

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                null, null, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");

        while (c.moveToNext()) {

            contactName = c
                    .getString(c
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            phNumber = c
                    .getString(c
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

        }
```